# Does syslog-ng support new line control characters in message?

Tags: linux, control-characters, syslog-ng

I've configured syslog-ng for a java application running on sles 10, when an exception occurs
it shows stack trace without new lines.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's available on version 3.5 of syslog-ng.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought so; at least I know rsyslogd can. Java stack traces can be very large quite large, so you may like to use TCP instead. I would recommend using the `logger` command to simulate the test, and using `tcpdump -s0 -A port syslog` to determine if the new-line characters are being transmitted.